# How to join 2 SQL tables with differing columns based on a condition?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have 2 tables: CT and AC

When CT.X = '1'
I want to inner join CT.A with AC.A

When CT.X = '2'
I want to inner join CT.B with AC.A

For any other CT.X
I want to inner join CT.C with AC.A

What is an elegant way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this should work:

```
select *
from CT
inner join AC
    on (CT.X = '1' and CT.A = AC.A)
    or (CT.X = '2' and CT.B = AC.A)
    or (CT.X <> '1' and CT.X <> '2' and CT.C = AC.A);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `left join` and choose the right columns in the `select` using `coalesce()`:

```
select ct.*,
       coalesce(ac1.col, ac2.col) as col
from ct left join
     ac ac1
     on ac1.a = ct.a and ct.x = 1 left join
     ac ac2
     on ac2.a = ct.c and ct.x = 2
```